# Package libsane-extras not found; is this a problem or should the instructions change?

Tags: ubuntu, sane

The instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/sane suggest installing `libsane-extras` as one of the packages to go along with `sane`.

As of June 2023, this package is not found in a standard Ubuntu/Pop!_OS package repository.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libsane-extras                                             
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libsane-extras
```

Which one is closer to the truth?

- We need to install `libsane-extras` for `sane` to work, so we need to find it somewhere else.
- We don't need `libsane-extras` any more for `sane` to work, so we should change the installation instructions.

...or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libsane-extras` is obsolete: it was [removed from Debian in 2018](https://bugs.debian.org/907796), and Ubuntu followed suit thereafter. The core `libsane` package contains newer libraries.

So the installation instructions should be changed.

Comment: I finally received authorization to fix this today and I did. Thank you for pointing me to the appropriate solution.